# Flutter: BottomAppBar icons with endDocked FAB don't align nicely.

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been stuck on this for awhile and haven't been able to find any answers from googling. I have a bottomAppBar with an endDocked Fab with 3 icons that are spaced out. However the icons don't take into account that the FAB is right above it, it results in spacing that is less than pleasant to the eye.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9COs.jpg

The first photo show what is currently happening, the second is closer to what i'm after, minus the white icon hidden behind the FAB.

Is there a way to tell flutter to say that the available space for the icon shouldn't overlap the endDocked FAB?

Thanks!

Code:

```
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF14172D),
      child: const Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      notchMargin: 4.0,
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.all_inclusive),
            color: Color(0xFF14172D),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            color: Color(0xFF14172D),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            color: Color(0xFF14172D),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just increase `BottomAppBar` with a non-visual widget. It is common to use `SizedBox` for paddings in Flutter, and so you may do the trick:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
  ...
  child: new Row(
    ...
    children: <Widget>[
      ...
     ,
    ],
  ),const SizedBox(width: 20.0)
...
```

Comment: You can use `SizedBox` but the really "correct" way is to add just another `IconButton` with  the `icon` being `Icon(null)`. That takes care of sizing automatically.